# How do I implement DevOps practices after gaining theoretical knowledge? What kind of projects should I develop for CI step? I’m not a heavy coder

Tags: web, github, continuous-integration, project, devops

I’m looking for suggestions, planning to practice what I’ve learnt about DevOps, what kind of projects to develop in order to start with CI step.Is it better to develop something from scratch or get the projects from github. I’m not a heavy coder.

Answer (score 0):

Start small and iterate.
If you want to proceed with the CI, set up the simplest codebase, like a function that sums two integers, configure an automation server (e.g. Jenkins) to build a bundle on each commit, write the simplest ever tests.

As the next step, you can add documentation to your project.